# error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop": executable file not found in %PATH%, out: `

Tags: python, django, windows, docker, docker-compose

I am working on a django project in window 10 Home, with docker desktop. When trying to create a multiple container with the command docker compose up -d (or docker-compose up -d) it gives me the following error:

```
$ docker compose up -d
[+] Running 0/1
mysql Pulling
error getting credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-desktop": executable file not found in %PATH%, out:
```

I have tried the following:

-Change the path found in the PATH of the environment variables, the original is **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin**, but if I change it to **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\ bin\docker.exe** or **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin\docker-compose.exe**, it gives me another error:

```
$ docker compose up -d
bash:docker:command not found
```

-I have also changed the value "credsStore" to "credStore" in the config-options.json file, as some users suggest in other similar cases, but it has no effect

I hope you can help me